# Conditionally require modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, if-statement, react-native

I'm entering the conditional as expected (as proven by a console that is only hit in the if statement if `process.env.BROWSER === true`, but the require inside the if statement is still getting hit nomatter if `process.env.BROWSER === true` or `process.env.BROWSER === false` and this is causing and error when `process.env.BROWSER === false`. If I comment out the first require, then when `process.env.BROWSER === false` there is no error.

I suspect that all requires are somehow called when JS is compiling, but if that's the case how can I conditionally require a module? What's exactly happening here?

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
    language['ES'].push(require('promise?global,locale-es-ES!react-intl/locale-data/es'));
} else{
    language['ES'].push(function () {
      return Promise.resolve(require('react-intl/locale-data/es'));
    });
}
```

using module.require like this works in react-native but throws a `TypeError: module.require is not a function` when in the Browser

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
    language['ES'].push(module.require('promise?global,locale-es-ES!react-intl/locale-data/es'));
} else{
    language['ES'].push(function () {
      return Promise.resolve(require('react-intl/locale-data/es'));
    });
}
```

trying to find a reference to module like this gives the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined`

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
        language['ES'].push(require('react-intl').module.require('promise?global,locale-es-ES!react-intl/locale-data/es'));
    } else{
        language['ES'].push(function () {
          return Promise.resolve(require('react-intl/locale-data/es'));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem as above but with nodejs and react native.

I overcame the problem by using `module.require()` for nodejs module. Try if you can do this in your case(Or any way to avoid a direct `require` for browser case).

React native would not allow conditional require, and I think does a static analysis loading all require before.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm getting this error in react-native too. It looks like in order to use module.require() though, I have to explicitly export `module` from react-intl. Is that what you had to do? https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id

Comment: What I meant was just use require for react-native and module.require for other environment. For me nodejs allowed me to do conditional require, only react-native was preventing it.

Comment: How did you use module.require without getting a TypeError: module.require is not a function

Comment: How did you get a reference to module to use module.require? p.s. I updated the question to show what I see when I try this.